# Trying to connect internally to Oracle, getting an idle instance?

Tags: oracle, instance, idle-processing

So I have an Oracle instance, and I know it's running on this system, I've su'd to the oracle user, and I'm trying to connect using "/ as sysdba".  However, when I do connect, it says the instance is idle.  I know the database is up and opened, because my application's talking to it.  My paths (ORACLE_HOME, etc.) might be incorrect: any idea which incorrect setting might result in this?

```
% sqlplus "/ as sysdba"

SQL*Plus: Release 10.2.0.3.0 - Production on Mon Dec 8 09:23:22 2008

Copyright (c) 1982, 2006, Oracle.  All Rights Reserved.

Connected to an idle instance.

09:23:22 SQL> Disconnected

% ps -ef | grep smon
 oracle  6961     1   0   Nov 05 ?           1:24 ora_smon_ORA003
%
```

Answer (score 16):

make sure you have your ORACLE_HOME setup exactly the same as when the server was started, I've seen this problem with oracle 9.2.0.5.0 on solaris,

```
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle
ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/
```

is two different things, and will result in issues connecting locally.

Answer (score 8):

that means that the database instance is not mounted nor open.  Execute the *startup* command and see if any errors appear.

Answer (score 4):

thanks. it indeed was that extra front slash at the end in ORACLE_HOME variable.

In my case, see the wierdness - I logged in to the server and tried connecting but got the above error. I knew that instance was up and DB was opened. So checked the ORACLE_HOME because I was sort of aware about this possibility. What I saw was that ORACLE_HOME was fine (i.e. no extra front slash at the end). Then after trying a lot when I read this thread, it struck me. The DB was started with ORACLE_HOME set with that extra front slash. So DB was started with 
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.3/
and all the while, I was trying with
ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/10.2.0.3
:(

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The database cannot be idle and in use by your application at the same time.  It seems like the sqlplus session must be connected to a different instance than the application.  Try specifying the connect identifier in the connect statement as follows:

```
sqlplus "/@ConnectIdentifier as sysdba"
```

Answer (score 2):

Case is significant on *nix systems, so make sure your ORACLE_SID exactly matches the instance name. In this case, ORA003 is NOT the same as ora003.

Answer (score 2):

try from the machine console

```
export ORACLE_SID=your sid here
sqlplus /nolog
startup
```

I know on windows there is a command to create a service to start up an instance for you,
oradmin -new -sid %ORACLE_SID% -intpwd %oracle_pwd% -startmode A

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. 
By removing the extra "/" at the end of ORACLE_HOME solved it.

Thanks for sharing - it would have been really difficult to diagnose and resolve this problem in the absence of this blog.

Comment: Gosh! It has solved my problem after 5 hours trying!!! Thanks. Obs: RHEL 7.2

Answer (score 2):

Try this Login with `sqlplus sys/sys as sysdba`

```
SQL> startup
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE LIKE:\n

```
Total System Global Area  467652608 bytes
Fixed Size          2214416 bytes
Variable Size         352323056 bytes
Database Buffers      104857600 bytes
Redo Buffers            8257536 bytes
Database mounted.
Database opened.
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok here's what i've Found out about instance idle
it has to do with the spfile.. sometimes your `init.ora` is located somewhere else

try to search for `init.ora`, once you found the location

try that code `startup spfile="C:\location";`

it will say that instance started.

well that one worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue while specify wrong SID (xe instead of XE).
If you install database with rpm, check all enviroment at /etc/inid.d/oracle

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be if the session could not be opened due to extremally busy database.
in this case connection using any user even dummy one

sqlplus dummy/dummy

would give you actual problem but not idle instance.

Answer (score 0):

I tried sqlplus dummy/dummy and it gave me the actual issue (out of memory). I made memory available and I was able to login without any issue.

Answer (score 0):

just type :

```
shutdown abort
```

then

```
startup
```